# Update commands on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-updates

What does each of these commands do:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Start by reading `man apt`

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, I am new to this site?

Comment: Manual is maybe too big. If you don't know anything from them, then better is to google for "apt tutorial" or so. Your question was closed because learning materials are here offtopic (if you want to know something, ask here directly). It is the rule, there is no bad intent behind that.

Comment: But I don't get what you mean by learning topics, what is this site for? Errors and things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apt-get update

> updates the local package database, so that your local system knows what is available
>
> "Run this command periodically to make sure your source list is up-to-date. "

apt-get upgrade

> upgrades all the packages with-in your current distribution that need updated to current with regard to the latest that the package database has.
>
> " This command upgrades all installed packages."

apt-get dist-upgrade

> " The same as the above, except add the "smart upgrade" checkbox. It tells APT to use "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary. "

[Package management with APT](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto